# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.stopSpeakingAtBoundary') (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, text-to-speech

My app is in ReactNative and targets both IOS and Android devices.
I'm using text to speech library

**IOS:**
**react-native-speech:**
https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-speech

**Android:**
**react-native-android-speech**
**https://github.com/mihirsoni/react-native-android-speech**

When running on the simulator it works both IOS and android.
But when running on a device, on android I get:

**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.stopSpeakingAtBoundary')**

Answer (score 0):

Posting this is someone will face the same issue,
This had nothing to do with speech, error happened only on the device because the localhost wasn't setup currectly.

Had to run this command first:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

By the doc:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html